# Can't update or refresh my datagrid when a form close

Tags: c#, datagrid

This is my code whenever `frmBorrow` close

```
    void borrowClose() 
    {
      frmBorrow br1 = new frmBorrow(this);
      br1.FormClosing += br1_FormClosing;
    }

    void br1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
      LoadTransactions();
    }

    void LoadTransactions()
    {
            cfgotcall.tether(settings);
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM tbltransactionbooks WHERE fBorrowDate LIKE '%" + txtSEARCH.Text.Trim() + "%'";
            cfgotcall.engageQuery(sql);
            unitbl = cfgotcall.tbl;

            sql = "SELECT fBarcodeNo AS 'Barcode No',fBookTitle AS 'Book',fStudent AS 'Student',fIDStudent AS 'Student ID',fStatus AS 'Status',fCourse AS 'Course',fBorrowDate AS 'Date Borrowed',fReturnDate AS 'Due Date',fAuthor AS 'Author',fAccNo AS 'Accession No.',fCallNo AS 'Call No.' FROM tbltransactionbooks WHERE fBorrowDate LIKE '%"
               + txtSEARCH.Text.Trim() + "%'";
            cfgotcall.engageQuery(sql);
            dgvDISPLAY.DataSource = cfgotcall.tbl;
            dgvDISPLAY.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
            cfgotcall.untether();
     }
```

Comment: i tried to debug my code that's why i tried to put in into constructor

Comment: no sir i didn't install it, consumes storage on my drive

Comment: its just 16 mb:P , anyway, did you debug and see?

Comment: still nothing happens

Comment: might have to debug and check, install tv and tell